# Avoid writing out latest commit hash when doing `git diff` after a merge

Tags: git, merge, diff

In a situation where I merged the latest commits from master into my working branch, I understand that I can check the `git diff` of any file staged for commit by simply running `git diff <hash> <file>` (or the first distinctive hexa chars for it).
But… can someone tell me if there is an option, to, by default, obtain the same behaviour, without having to go and look for these hash characters? (SVN looks for the latest release by default).

My intuition is that, since the latest commit hash is known by Git, somehow Git could just use that latest commit hash by default, or is it too much to ask of it?
It is a pain to go and fish out for this hash… and not my job! It should be the computer’s.

Answer (score 1):

In Git, the revision name **`HEAD`** always refers to the latest commit on your current branch (or directly to a commit if you did `git checkout a38ff0` instead of `git checkout my-branch`). So you can just put your filename into this command template:

```
git diff HEAD <file>
```

Also, if you need to refer to the commit prior to head, you can write `HEAD~`. And for two commits prior to head, you can write `HEAD~2` and so on. Also, `HEAD~~` and `HEAD^^` are equivalents to `HEAD~2`. (`HEAD^2` means something different though.)

Perhaps you are wondering why you can’t just write the following:

```
git diff <file>
```

This is equivalent only if you haven’t staged (`git add`ed) any changes. It diffs the file against the latest commit plus staged changes, instead of only the latest commit as happens when you specify `HEAD`.

Comment: Thank you @Rory for the augmented answer (the role of tilde).

Comment: Re: your added comment: indeed, I had figured this out about the unstaged changes, I couldn't figure out why the diff output had disappeared once staged.

Comment: Side note: `HEAD~~` and `HEAD~2` are equivalent, but `HEAD^^` and `HEAD^2` are not, and `HEAD~2` isn't equivalent to `HEAD^2` even nearly.